# I have problem in django's dynamic urls system

Tags: django-models, django-views

I have been following this other tutorial on youtube on build a project of some sort.its been days trying to find the solution to the problem

I tried using the 'str' and the 'int'

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('products/', views.products),
    path('customer/<int:my_id>/', views.customer),
]
```

this is my code in the views.py

```
def customer(request, my_id):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=my_id)
    orders = customer.order_set.all()

    context = {'customer': customer, 'orders': orders}
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer.htm', context)
```

please HELP

Comment: Exactly *what* is the problem? What URL can't you pass, what error appears? What is not working?

Comment: it keeps on saying " Page not found (404)"